# how do I add column filtering in react data-table

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

I am displaying real time data on react data-table.I have added a global filter but I need to add filter to each column

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

We have extended package name called **react-data-table-component-with-filter** there you just need to pass filterable: true then you will get filter option column wise

https://anothercodeartist.github.io/react-data-table-component/?path=/docs/getting-started-kitchen-sink--kitchen-sink

[image]